# postgresql- select records based on field length inner join information_schema.columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

I have two tables:1. `create table table_1(col1 text,col2 text)` 2. `create table table_2(tcol1 character varying(5), tcol2 character varying(5))`. 
table_1 has 50 records and table_2 is empty. I need to load those records from table_1 to table_2 if the length of table_2.tcol1 <= length of table_1.col1 and length of table_2.tcol2 <= length of table_1.col2. 
I can do this like:

```
insert into table_2(tcol1,tcol2)
select  col1,col2 from table_1
where char_length(col1) <=5 and char_length(col2) <=5
```

But in practical I have 100+ columns. Is there a way to achieve this by joining table_1 with information_schema.columns. The problem here is columns in table_1 are rows in information_schema.columns. Thanks for your interest in this question.

Comment: For this you will have to most probably generate query into string and run it using `EXECUTE`. If you could post `CREATE TABLE` commands for both tables I will take a look at it. Because from description I am not sure about structures.

Comment: have added create commands

Comment: ok :-) I meant real tables but never mind - see in answer...

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
with tab2cols as (select table_schema, table_name, column_name, character_maximum_length, ordinal_position from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'table_2' and ordinal_position > 0),
tab1cols as (select table_schema, table_name, column_name, character_maximum_length, ordinal_position from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'table_1' and ordinal_position > 0),
tab1sel as (select 'select '||string_agg(column_name,',' order by ordinal_position)||' from '||table_schema||'.'||table_name as select_string from tab1cols group by table_schema, table_name),
tab2ins as (select 'insert into '||table_schema||'.'||table_name||' ('||string_agg(column_name,',' order by ordinal_position)||') 'as insert_string from tab2cols group by table_schema, table_name)
select string_agg(_text, ' ') from (
    select insert_string as _text from tab2ins
    union all
    select select_string||' where ' as _text from tab1sel
    union all
    select string_agg('char_length('||t1.column_name||')<='||t2.character_maximum_length, ' AND ') as _text from tab2cols t2 join tab1cols t1 on t2.ordinal_position=t1.ordinal_position
) a
```

It will give you string like 
"insert into myschema.table_2 (tcol1,tcol2)  select col1,col2 from myschema.table_1 where  char_length(col1)<=5 AND char_length(col2)<=5" which you can run in `EXECUTE` command or where ever you want.

I wrote it with CTE so all parts are clearly visible. Of course there are ways how to write it shorter etc... :-)